# Does using the ++ or -- operator on different variables in the same expression invoke UB?

Tags: c, increment, decrement

I wanted to know whether using the increment(`++`) or the decrement(`--`) operator on different variables in the same expression undefined behavior; Such as

```
int i=1,j=2;
int k=i++ + j++;
```

In the above code,the value of `k` is 3 in [clang](http://rextester.com/ZSQO23124),[GCC](http://rextester.com/JFP19845) and in [vc](http://rextester.com/MLZ74204).

Comment: why write such code? BTW - This "popular" question has been asked many times. Just do one thing at a time and you cannot go far wrong

Comment: @EdHeal This question is asked many times but people just don't know to look on 'sequence points' as term when looking up this question

Comment: @hetepeperfan One can find all the explanations one needs by searching “increment undefined behavior”, all words that the OP definitely knows.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Does using the ++ or — operator on different variables in the same expression invoke UB?

No. It will not invoke *undefined behavior*. You can use `++` or `--` any number of times in a expression on different objects.  In this case each variable is modifying only once within two sequence points.

Comment: But isn't the answser yes then, the OP uses two variables, thus `k` becomes three?

Comment: So long as it is a different variable `int a=0, *p=&a; b=++a+(*p)--;` gives undefined behavior because `*p` and `a` are the same object.

Comment: @hetepeperfan; Yes. Value of `k` will be 3. I answered about UB.